# supabase and hasura local dev: pg invalid response to SSL negotiation

Tags: localhost, hasura, supabase

Existing project managed with hasura{cli, console}.
Already migrated pg database from heroku-to-supabase.

The goal is to use SupabaseClient on the backend (with NextApiRequest handlers) for image/uploads

```
supabaseClient.storage.from(bucketId).upload(filePath, file, {
        contentType,
      })
```

I want to continue with apollo/client on the front.

Errors and problems encountered while setting local environment and trying to connect hasura/graphql-engine with supabase_network_app and more importantly supabase_db_app while removing current postgres image from docker-compose.yml:

- supabase_db_app refusing connection
- invalid response was received from the upstream server

  - cause: supabase_auth_app image.
  - ERROR: no schema has been selected to create
  - ERROR: Migrator: problem creating schema migrations
- ERROR: extension "pg_graphql" must be installed in schema "graphql"
- postgres local port 54322 failed: received invalid response to SSL negotiation

[wip] solution:
supabase init and start as per supabase documentation

/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  hasura:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.15.1
    container_name: hasura
    networks:
      - default
      - supabase_network_app
    ports:
      - 8081:8080 # supabase_pg_meta_app also runs on 8080/tcp
    # depends_on:
    #   - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@192.168.0.2:5432/postgres
      #feel free to replace/test with:       postgres://postgres:postgres@host.docker.internal:54322/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_REMOTE_SCHEMA_PERMISSIONS: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: $HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{ "type": "RS512", "jwk_url": "$AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL/.well-known/jwks.json" }'
 
networks:
  supabase_network_app:
    name: supabase_network_app
    external: true
    driver: bridge
```

Apply migration/metadata/seeds as usual with hasura

to keep things consistent and avoid manually applying and granting pg storage permissions:
create dump from supabase ref:

```
pg_dump --clean --if-exists --quote-all-identifiers \
 -h SUPABASE_URL -U postgres -d postgres \
  > supabase_dump.sql
```

and apply to local dev:

```
psql -h localhost -p 54322 -U postgres -f supabase_dump.sql
```

- this also helps supabase_auth_app container to start with no errors.

What's your experience with hasura/graphql-engine and supabase in local dev?